# MapReduce: How to join 2 tables: R(a,b) x S(c,d) where b<c

Tags: database, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

Given in each record, you have

```
Table_name(R/S) | attribute_1(a/c) | attribute_2(b/d)
.
.
.
```

For example this can be content of the input file:

```
R|$a_1$|$b_1$
R|$a_2$|$b_2$
S|$c_1$|$d_1$
R|$a_3$|$b_3$
S|$c_2$|$d_2$
```

An output is lines of:

```
$a_i$|$b_i$|$c_j$|$d_j$
```

,where $b_i < c_j$

(This is an exercise in the book "Mining of Massive Datasets". It is on the page 22 of this link: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch2.pdf (exercise 2.3.5). the book is freely available)

I've spend half a day and look over internet and still have no clue how to solve it...

Comment: The book's name is "Mining of Massive Datasets". It is on the page 22 of this link: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch2.pdf (exercise 2.3.5). the book is freely available.

Comment: What form is the answer supposed take? Please give an example/reference for another algorithm in the same form. (Eg natural join.)